# Installing Ipython - command Line

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

Im currently installing Ipython for a school project. Im doing it through windows command line using the command "pip install ipython" and I always get this error in the end:

WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-ni1wof-record\install-record.txt'

I already reinstalled Python 2.7 but didn't change a thing. I also restarted the computer.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does IPython work? If so, don't worry about it.

Comment: @MattDMo the problem is that it doesn't work :c

Comment: Receiving the exact same error message when trying to install sphinx-js.